# How to Draw xsd in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw with xsd in TikZ?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  It would be helpful to show that you made some attempt and ask a question about a specific problem you are having with the drawing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you provide a [mwe](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to see what have you done so far?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

Second attempt. You need to add some styles to simplify the code. A good way is to create new shapes but it's a long work. Here I saved some pictures with savedbox then you can reuse them inside new nodes but you need to take some precautions like `inner xsep=0`.
A problem is to get the same height inside rectangle spli part. here i used `\mystrut`but perhaps there is a batter method to do this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart} 

\def\vstrut{\vrule height 0.75ex depth 0.75ex width 0pt}
 \def\hstrut{\vrule height 0ex depth 0ex width 3mm}  
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\figone}
\savebox{\figone}{%    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (-2mm,-1mm) rectangle  (2mm,1mm); 
\fill[yshift=3mm] (-2mm,-1mm) rectangle  (2mm,1mm); 
\fill[yshift=-3mm ] (-2mm,-1mm) rectangle  (2mm,1mm);
\draw[thick] (-6mm,0) -- (-2mm,0)  (6mm,0) -- (2mm,0) ; 
\draw[thick]  (-2mm,-3mm) -- ++(-2mm,0) -- ++(0mm,6mm)--++(2mm,0);
\draw[thick]  (2mm,-3mm) -- ++(2mm,0) -- ++(0mm,6mm)--++(-2mm,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newsavebox{\figtwo}
\savebox{\figtwo}{%    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0mm,-3mm)--++(0,6mm)--++(3mm,3mm)--++(15mm,0)--++(3mm,-3mm)--++(0,-6mm)--++(-3mm,-3mm)--++(-15mm,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}   

\newsavebox{\tiret}
\savebox{\tiret}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (-2mm,0mm)--++(4mm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}% 

\newsavebox{\connect} 
\savebox{\connect}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{\usebox\figone};
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (ft){\usebox\figtwo};
  \node[draw,minimum size=6mm,anchor=center,inner sep=0pt,fill=white,inner xsep=0](m) at (ft.east){};
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (m) {\usebox\tiret};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\tikzset{split style/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw,rectangle split part align={left}}}

 \tikzset{square/.style={draw,minimum size=6mm,anchor=center,inner xsep=0pt,fill=white}}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,scale=.75,transform shape]
 \node[split style] (r1)
    {\vstrut\textbf{Root}\hstrut
    \nodepart{two} \vstrut type = Well\hstrut};
 \node[square] (b1) at (r1.east) {\usebox\tiret};
 \node[inner sep=0,anchor=west] (c1) at ([xshift=.5cm]b1.east){\usebox\connect};

 \node[split style,anchor=west] (r2) at ([xshift=0.5cm]c1.east)
    {\vstrut\textbf{BasicInfo}  1.1\hstrut
     \nodepart{two}
     \vstrut   type = Complex Type\hstrut};
  \node[square] (b2) at (r2.east) {\usebox\tiret};  
  \node[inner sep=0,anchor=west] (c2) at ([xshift=0.5cm]b2.east){\usebox\connect};    
  \draw (b1)-- (c1) (c1)-- (r2) (b2) --(c2);   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Youra_P No, the shapes in your example are not standard. Perhaps you can find a simplest way to make your drawing.